# How to extract data starting from date1 "2014-9-01" ending in April 2015 in data frame?

Tags: r

I am trying to extract data from September, 2014 to April, 2015 but it still give me wrong data from April to September, 2014 and only April, 2015 using the following code

```
#Reading RainWind.csv file, Filter by year & Month
W <- function() { 
  z <- read.csv("RainWind.csv")
  z <- z[z$Year==2014|z$Year==2015,]
  z <- z[z$Year %in% "2014":"2015" & z$Month %in% 9:4,]
  z
}
w <- W()
```

Comment: We need more information: What are the classes of Year and Month? (Try class(z$Year) and class(z$Month).

Comment: You could convert to `Date` class by joining the columns and then extract it.

Comment: @akrun   how to do that ??

Comment: @Helix123  Sorry i meant Integer

Comment: I just need to extract data from September 2014 to April 2015 only from that cs. file

Comment: It would be better if you show few lines of data

Comment: You want data from september to april, but you only select months `9:4`, so april to september. It's hard to answer your question without seeing what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesized test data:

```
testdates <- seq(as.Date('2013-12-01'),as.Date('2016-01-01'),by='month');
z <- data.frame(Year=as.integer(strftime(testdates,'%Y')),Month=as.integer(strftime(testdates,'%m')));
z;
##    Year Month
## 1  2013    12
## 2  2014     1
## 3  2014     2
## 4  2014     3
## 5  2014     4
## 6  2014     5
## 7  2014     6
## 8  2014     7
## 9  2014     8
## 10 2014     9
## 11 2014    10
## 12 2014    11
## 13 2014    12
## 14 2015     1
## 15 2015     2
## 16 2015     3
## 17 2015     4
## 18 2015     5
## 19 2015     6
## 20 2015     7
## 21 2015     8
## 22 2015     9
## 23 2015    10
## 24 2015    11
## 25 2015    12
## 26 2016     1
```

Assuming `z$Year` and `z$Month` are integer, and `z$Month` uses month numbers 1-12, as in my test data:

```
z[(z$Year==2014 & z$Month>=9) | (z$Year==2015 & z$Month<=4),];
##    Year Month
## 10 2014     9
## 11 2014    10
## 12 2014    11
## 13 2014    12
## 14 2015     1
## 15 2015     2
## 16 2015     3
## 17 2015     4
```

---

As an alternative, you could combine the date fields into a new Date column of type Date, and then filtering for a range would be easier, since you could use the standard comparison operators:

```
z$Date <- as.Date(sprintf('%04d-%02d-01',z$Year,z$Month));
z;
##    Year Month       Date
## 1  2013    12 2013-12-01
## 2  2014     1 2014-01-01
## 3  2014     2 2014-02-01
## 4  2014     3 2014-03-01
## 5  2014     4 2014-04-01
## 6  2014     5 2014-05-01
## 7  2014     6 2014-06-01
## 8  2014     7 2014-07-01
## 9  2014     8 2014-08-01
## 10 2014     9 2014-09-01
## 11 2014    10 2014-10-01
## 12 2014    11 2014-11-01
## 13 2014    12 2014-12-01
## 14 2015     1 2015-01-01
## 15 2015     2 2015-02-01
## 16 2015     3 2015-03-01
## 17 2015     4 2015-04-01
## 18 2015     5 2015-05-01
## 19 2015     6 2015-06-01
## 20 2015     7 2015-07-01
## 21 2015     8 2015-08-01
## 22 2015     9 2015-09-01
## 23 2015    10 2015-10-01
## 24 2015    11 2015-11-01
## 25 2015    12 2015-12-01
## 26 2016     1 2016-01-01
z[z$Date>=as.Date('2014-09-01') & z$Date<as.Date('2015-05-01'),];
##    Year Month       Date
## 10 2014     9 2014-09-01
## 11 2014    10 2014-10-01
## 12 2014    11 2014-11-01
## 13 2014    12 2014-12-01
## 14 2015     1 2015-01-01
## 15 2015     2 2015-02-01
## 16 2015     3 2015-03-01
## 17 2015     4 2015-04-01
```

Comment: you are my hero   thank you very much boss  this one work z[(z$Year==2014 & z$Month>=9) | (z$Year==2015 & z$Month<=4),];